# Синхронизация пакетов в проектах - NetBeans.

Tags: android, java, netbeans

Существуют две программы. Сервер - под комп, и клиент игры на андроиде. Проекты в нетбинсе. В каждом проекте есть пакет - server или client, в которых содержатся классы, необходимые только клиенту/серверу, и + в каждом проекте есть пакет common, который содержит классы общие (идентичные для обоих проектов). Вопрос: как синхронизировать эти пакеты? Возможно, стоит вывести эти классы в библиотеку?

Comment: bump.
Неужели ни у кого нет идей?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, а зачем синхронизировать? И главное что синхронизировать? Объектные коды? Так они для сервера и клиента все равно разные. Серверные коды работают под стандартный JVM, а телефонные под Dalvik VM - они на уровне байткодов все равно несовместимы.

Так что имеет смысл разве что синхронизировать исходники: заведите исходники под контроль версий и пропишите статическую функцию в серверной и клиентской части которая возвращает текущую версию. При запуске можно в рантайме проверять версии сервера и клиента и в случае необходимости писать нечто интеллектуальное типа: "устаревшая версия"...

**Update**
А что разве Netbeans разучился собирать несколько проектов из одного дерева исходников? В общем загоните все исходники под 3 каталога, скажем: src/server, src/common, src/client. Далее создаете проект для сервера в качестве исходников используете каталоги src/server и src/common. Аналогично проект для клиента: src/common и src/client

Comment: Наверное, вы меня не совсем поняли. Два проекта имеют общие исходники, и менять ручками исходники в одном проекте, когда меняешь их в другом, не комильфо. Так у меня и появилась идея - может эти общие исходники выделить в библиотеку, чтобы подключить ее к проектам клиента и сервера. Может, есть более рациональное решение, о котором я тут и спрашиваю.

Comment: зачем велик делать? если есть исходники, который можно использовать как либу - выноси в либу, если нет - просто скопируй 1-2а класса и все. Если же.... вообще то как то глупо, но если они пишутся параллельно... то... ну я даже не знаю, мавен как-то надо настроить, что бы подтягивал последнии версии

Comment: ыыыы, прочитал вопрос =) реально, как это у клиента и сервера есть общие части? имхо, как-то не правильная организация проекта..

Comment: @Phynn: обновил ответ